# scroll other scrollbars with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

i have 3 divs with scrollbars.
If i scroll in div 1 i want to scroll div 2 and 3 in the opposite direction.
The distance scrolled should be half the distance of div 1.

This is what i have now (small part, rest is in jsfiddle), which works for 1 div.

```
$("#textBox1").scroll(function () {
        console.log("scroll 1");
        var offset = $("#textBox1").scrollTop() - scrollPosTBox1;
        var half_offset = offset/2.0;

        disable1 = true;

        if(disable2 == false) {
            $("#textBox2").scrollTop(scrollPosTBox2 - half_offset);
        }
        if(disable3 == false) {
            $("#textBox3").scrollTop(scrollPosTBox3 - half_offset);
        }    
        disable1 = false;


    });
```

However, if i try to get the same for the other 2 divs then i can't scroll anything anymore.
This is because div 1 triggers div 2 and div 2 triggers back to div 1 for example.
I tried to fix this with the disable code but it doesn't help.

Can someone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/XmYh5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No disrespect to @EmreErkan and @Simon for their effort. Here's a no-click version of this.

```
var $boxes = $("#textBox1,#textBox2,#textBox3"),
    active;

$boxes.scrollTop(150);

// set initial scrollTop values
updateScrollPos();

// bind mouseenter: 
// 1) find which panel is active 
// 2) update scrollTop values

$boxes.mouseenter(function () {
    active = this.id;
    updateScrollPos();
});

// bind scroll for all boxes
$boxes.scroll(function (e) {

    $this = $(this);

    // check to see if we are dealing with the active box
    // if true then set scrolltop of other boxes relative to the active box
    if(this.id == active){

        var $others = $boxes.not($this),
            offset = $this.scrollTop()-$this.data("scroll"),
            half_offset = offset / 2;

        $others.each(function(){
            $this = $(this);
            $this.scrollTop($this.data("scroll") - half_offset);
        });
    }

});

// utility function: 
// assign scrollTop values element's data attributes (data-scroll)

function updateScrollPos() {
    $boxes.each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data("scroll",$this.scrollTop());
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmYh5/16/)

Comment: @Simon My scroll event was all over the place, added a check for the active box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to determine active textbox with `.mousedown()` and do the trick if it's active;

```
var activeScroll = '';

$("#textBox1").on('mousedown focus mouseenter', function () {
    activeScroll = 'scroll1';
}).scroll(function () {
    if (activeScroll == 'scroll1') {
        console.log("scroll 1");
        var offset = $("#textBox1").scrollTop() - scrollPosTBox1;
        var half_offset = offset / 2.0;

        $("#textBox2").scrollTop(scrollPosTBox2 - half_offset);
        $("#textBox3").scrollTop(scrollPosTBox3 - half_offset);
    }
});
```

You can check your updated [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/XmYh5/12/).

Comment: hi thanks, looks good but it can't go into: `if (activeScroll == 'scroll1') {` I added `console.log("active! 1");` after the curly brace but i never see the message in the console.

Comment: yeah activeScroll stays empty for some reason

Comment: Can you please show your code with jsFiddle? I put `console.log("scroll 1")` after curly brace and it shows only "scroll 1" when you scroll `textbox1` [example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/XmYh5/7/)

Comment: here: http://jsfiddle.net/XmYh5/8/ check the first 1. line 15 for example is always ''

Comment: Yes, because it's not in the if statement. On every scroll every scroll event of textboxes will fire but due to if statements only active textbox's scroll function will work. If you move your `console.log()` call inside of if statement you'll see it will log only when you scroll first textbox. [Check my updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/XmYh5/9/)

Comment: ah i just noticed i have to click to make it work, i didn't click before. Kinda makes sense for mouseDown :)

Comment: You're right. There is more than one ways to scroll a div; wheel, keyboard etc. So I updated my answer a little bit. This is much more responsive.

Comment: Most thx goes still to you Emre Erkan, someone needed it for a school asignment asap and without you he would have failed.
But for the quality of darshanags i choosed his answer as best solution since it doesn't require a mousePress.
But still thx!

Comment: No problem. It's ok for me but for future visitors, I also updated my answer to not require mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a dynamic solution for this, was more complex than I thought but I think I got it:

http://jsfiddle.net/XmYh5/14/

```
var initialTop = 150,
    factor = 2;

    $(".textBox")
        .addClass('disabled')
        .scrollTop(initialTop)
        .on('scroll', function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            if(!$this.is('.disabled')) {
                this.lastOffset = this.lastOffset || initialTop;

                var offset = $this.scrollTop(),
                    step = (offset - this.lastOffset) / factor;

                $this.siblings().each( function() {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        offset = $this.scrollTop() - step;

                    $this.scrollTop(offset);
                    this.lastOffset = offset;
                });

                this.lastOffset = offset;
            }
        })
        .on('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('disabled').siblings().addClass('disabled');
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does now"?