# How to synchronize scroll between two elements with different height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two DIV elements `#page` and `#block` :

```
<div id="page"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
```

`#block` element has fixed position and long content inside with `overflow:hidden` property.

`#page` element has some content inside too, but it height of `#page` will be longer or shorter then `#block` height.

My goal is to achieve synchronized scroll between this two elements. Something like this:

[image]

I need to calculate speed of `#block` element scroll, because header and footer elements of `#page` and `#block` should be at same position from beginning and at the end of scroll.

**The way I tried to achieve this:**

- Calculated height of `#page` element
- Calculated height of `#block` element content (because block element is fixed and has alwas fixed height)
- Calculated `#block` element scroll speed by:

  `$("#block").outerHeight / $("#page").outerHeight`
- Triggered `.scrollTop()` of `#block`

It's working from the beginning and `#block` element scroll is faster then `#page` element scroll, but at the end, `#block` is not scrolled fully.

Here is my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/bQYrf/2/

Maybe anyone can see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must take the `window height` into the case and subtract it from the elements heights.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var pageH = $('#page').height() - $(this).height();
    var pageT = this.scrollY - $('#page').offset().top;

    $('#block').scrollTop(pageT / pageH * ($('#blockLength').height() - $(this).height()));
});
```

### Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bQYrf/4/

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am posting this on behalf of [Burak Birer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6307832/burak-birer) who has posted this comment as an answer; _@matewka it seems i cannot comment yet. The only problem with the example is that when there is few text on one coloumn you simply cannot scroll the long one. Do you think there might be a fix for this situation?_

Answer (score 3):

I have found two examples of this same question already answered in SO:

If I understand you question correctly this is exactly what you are looking for:
[Synchronized scrolling using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952623/synchronized-scrolling-using-jquery)

This is also a good solution:
[How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getClientHeight()
{
  return document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && !window.opera?document.documentElement.clientHeight:document.body.clientHeight;
}

var clientHeight = getClientHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var diff = ($("#blockLength").height() - clientHeight) / ($("#page").height() - clientHeight);
    var blocktoSet = $(window).scrollTop() * diff;

    $("#block").scrollTop(blocktoSet);

    console.log()



});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PeGky/1/