# synchronized scrolling for 3(+) elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, synchronization, percentage

I am trying to implement synchronized scrolling for more than two DIV using the code below as a launching point. All DIV are same height and width, with a varying number of characters. The percentage sync works perfectly for #div1 and #div2 (it's really quite beautiful). But I'm unable to get the third DIV to behave despite hours of fiddling (everything I've tried is glitchy and clunky). I'm new to this so I'm hoping someone can assist!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $divs = $('#div1, #div2');
var sync = function(e){
var $other = $divs.not(this).off('scroll'), other = $other.get(0);
var percentage = this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight);
other.scrollTop = percentage * (other.scrollHeight - other.offsetHeight);
setTimeout( function(){ $other.on('scroll', sync ); },10);
}
$divs.on( 'scroll', sync);
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/84oz9boL/11](http://jsfiddle.net/84oz9boL/11/) When I add ,#div3 the scrolls behave erratically...

```js
var $divs = $('#div1, #div2');
var sync = function(e){
    var $other = $divs.not(this).off('scroll'), other = $other.get(0);
    var percentage = this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight);
    other.scrollTop = percentage * (other.scrollHeight - other.offsetHeight);
    setTimeout( function(){ $other.on('scroll', sync ); },10);
}
$divs.on( 'scroll', sync);
```

```css
div {
    overflow: scroll;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
}
#div1 {
    height : 400px;
    width: 200px;
}
#div2 {
    height : 400px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#div3 {
    height : 400px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in neque aliquam, blandit purus id, consequat ex. Quisque efficitur orci nunc, a sodales sapien vehicula et. Proin dignissim facilisis felis, sit amet placerat odio vehicula sed. Quisque vulputate eros magna, nec scelerisque augue auctor id. Pellentesque mi elit, malesuada imperdiet efficitur luctus, scelerisque nec nisi. Nulla eget volutpat elit, in ornare lacus. Suspendisse sit amet lacus nec ipsum luctus semper. Mauris ipsum eros, laoreet dignissim elementum ac, viverra sed est. Aenean aliquet tempor justo, non hendrerit massa convallis ac. Aenean volutpat consectetur ex, a sodales sem tincidunt et. Donec volutpat ante eu odio ornare malesuada. Sed dignissim purus lacinia tempor sagittis. Nam quis arcu massa. Nam neque sem, dignissim sit amet congue quis, rutrum vel quam. Nunc ut porta sem. Maecenas suscipit lacus at interdum aliquam. In aliquam turpis eget arcu faucibus, sit amet vulputate purus ornare. Fusce vitae nisi odio. Nunc eget bibendum magna, eget eleifend massa. Nullam eu dui at nunc eleifend lacinia tincidunt a lorem. Pellentesque egestas fermentum est, vitae rutrum turpis rhoncus quis. Etiam in rhoncus tellus. Morbi tellus erat, laoreet at lectus sed, efficitur vestibulum lorem. Fusce tempus, quam nec feugiat ornare, velit nisl ultricies tortor, id elementum ex lectus et sem. Donec ornare ante sed elit sollicitudin tempor.
</div>

<div id="div2">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in neque aliquam, blandit purus id, consequat ex. Quisque efficitur orci nunc, a sodales sapien vehicula et. Proin dignissim facilisis felis, sit amet placerat odio vehicula sed. Quisque vulputate eros magna, nec scelerisque augue auctor id. Pellentesque mi elit, malesuada imperdiet efficitur luctus, scelerisque nec nisi. Nulla eget volutpat elit, in ornare lacus. Suspendisse sit amet lacus nec ipsum luctus semper. Mauris ipsum eros, laoreet dignissim elementum ac, viverra sed est. Aenean aliquet tempor justo, non hendrerit massa convallis ac. Aenean volutpat consectetur ex, a sodales sem tincidunt et. Donec volutpat ante eu odio ornare malesuada. Sed dignissim purus lacinia tempor sagittis. Nam quis arcu massa. Nam neque sem, dignissim sit amet congue quis, rutrum vel quam. Nunc ut porta sem. Maecenas suscipit lacus at interdum aliquam. In aliquam turpis eget arcu faucibus, sit amet vulputate purus ornare. Fusce vitae nisi odio. Nunc eget bibendum magna, eget eleifend massa. Nullam eu dui at nunc eleifend lacinia tincidunt a lorem. Pellentesque egestas fermentum est, vitae rutrum turpis rhoncus quis. Etiam in rhoncus tellus. Morbi tellus erat, laoreet at lectus sed, efficitur vestibulum lorem. Fusce tempus, quam nec feugiat ornare, velit nisl ultricies tortor, id elementum ex lectus et sem. Donec ornare ante sed elit sollicitudin tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in neque aliquam, blandit purus id, consequat ex. Quisque efficitur orci nunc, a sodales sapien vehicula et. Proin dignissim facilisis felis, sit amet placerat odio vehicula sed. Quisque vulputate eros magna, nec scelerisque augue auctor id. Pellentesque mi elit, malesuada imperdiet efficitur luctus, scelerisque nec nisi. Nulla eget volutpat elit, in ornare lacus. Suspendisse sit amet lacus nec ipsum luctus semper. Mauris ipsum eros, laoreet dignissim elementum ac, viverra sed est. Aenean aliquet tempor justo, non hendrerit massa convallis ac. Aenean volutpat consectetur ex, a sodales sem tincidunt et. Donec volutpat ante eu odio ornare malesuada. Sed dignissim purus lacinia tempor sagittis. Nam quis arcu massa. Nam neque sem, dignissim sit amet congue quis, rutrum vel quam. Nunc ut porta sem. Maecenas suscipit lacus at interdum aliquam. In aliquam turpis eget arcu faucibus, sit amet vulputate purus ornare. Fusce vitae nisi odio. Nunc eget bibendum magna, eget eleifend massa. Nullam eu dui at nunc eleifend lacinia tincidunt a lorem. Pellentesque egestas fermentum est, vitae rutrum turpis rhoncus quis. Etiam in rhoncus tellus. Morbi tellus erat, laoreet at lectus sed, efficitur vestibulum lorem. Fusce tempus, quam nec feugiat ornare, velit nisl ultricies tortor, id elementum ex lectus et sem. Donec ornare ante sed elit sollicitudin tempor.
</div>

<div id="div3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in neque aliquam, blandit purus id, consequat ex. Quisque efficitur orci nunc, a sodales sapien vehicula et. Proin dignissim facilisis felis, sit amet placerat odio vehicula sed. Quisque vulputate eros magna, nec scelerisque augue auctor id. Pellentesque mi elit, malesuada imperdiet efficitur luctus, scelerisque nec nisi. Nulla eget volutpat elit, in ornare lacus. Suspendisse sit amet lacus nec ipsum luctus semper. Mauris ipsum eros, laoreet dignissim elementum ac, viverra sed est. Aenean aliquet tempor justo, non hendrerit massa convallis ac. Aenean volutpat consectetur ex, a sodales sem tincidunt et. Donec volutpat ante eu odio ornare malesuada. Sed dignissim purus lacinia tempor sagittis. Nam quis arcu massa. Nam neque sem, dignissim sit amet congue quis, rutrum vel quam. Nunc ut porta sem. Maecenas suscipit lacus at interdum aliquam. In aliquam turpis eget arcu faucibus, sit amet vulputate purus ornare. Fusce vitae nisi odio. Nunc eget bibendum magna, eget eleifend massa. Nullam eu dui at nunc eleifend lacinia tincidunt a lorem. Pellentesque egestas fermentum est, vitae rutrum turpis rhoncus quis. Etiam in rhoncus tellus. Morbi tellus erat, laoreet at lectus sed, efficitur vestibulum lorem. Fusce tempus, quam nec feugiat ornare, velit nisl ultricies tortor, id elementum ex lectus et sem. Donec ornare ante sed elit sollicitudin tempor.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or better, yet a [stack snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we can see this behavior too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're referencing multiple divs, you need to treat apply the scrollTop to each one of them. In you current code, you write `other.get(0)`, which only target the first of the siblings.

I rewrote your code below to iterate over the array of siblings. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/84oz9boL/16/

```
var $divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3');
var sync = function(e){
    var $other = $divs.not(this).off('scroll'), 
        percentage = this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight);

    $other.each(function (index, other) {
        other.scrollTop = percentage * (other.scrollHeight - other.offsetHeight);
    });
    setTimeout( function(){ $other.on('scroll', sync ); },10);
}
$divs.on( 'scroll', sync);
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/84oz9boL/11

Comment: @helenscott Updated, works now. You needed to iterate over each object.

Comment: If you scroll in the boxes a strange bug appears where it keeps scrolling.
I've fixed the issue and made the plugin from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34017855/63467

Answer (score 0):

If performance is the issue, have you tried not constructing `other` at all and just defining `percentage`, turning off the scroll on `.not(this)` elements, then going with `$divs.not(this).scrollTop = percentage * ($divs.not(this).scrollHeight - $divs.not(this).offsetHeight)`?

Comment: On second thought, this is probably dumb, because I can't imagine the whole "taking the difference of two collections" performing intuitively.