# Comparing two data grids

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have two data grids side by side in my html page to compare their data. Just like this image:

[image: Beyond Compare]

Is there any free java script library which supports such feature?

Comment: Try using a `frame`

Comment: Can you explain more

Comment: The problem is syncing the scrolling between these grids

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronized scrolling using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952623/synchronized-scrolling-using-jquery)